# Why is "感恩" frequently used as a verb?

Tags: meaning, mandarin, vocabulary, difference

In the last two years or so I began to see people frequently using 感恩 as verb meaning "thank (you)", such as "感恩大家" or "感恩领导".

But I thought "感恩" is a verb-noun phrase, meaning "thank (you for your) kindness", while "感谢" is the phrase for "thank (you)".

Is the use of "感恩" instead of "感谢" a newly emerged usage, or have the two always been interchangeable?

Comment: Because these people are either movie star or working for the nation, they are too busy , don't  have enough time to learn.

Comment: This is how we say thank you in Vietnamese (cám ơn) or cảm ân when pronounced in Sino-Vietnamese.

Answer (score 4):

You are right that **感恩** is a verb-noun phrase. When another noun is appended (i.e. **感恩XX**), it means that you are thanking (**感**) someone (**XX**) for their kindness (**恩**). Inversion is at play here. 
**"感恩"** carries a degree of formality and is rarely used in daily conversation. It will be awkward if someone uses **"感恩"** when not speaking publicly.
To rate them in terms of formalities: **感恩** > **感谢** > **谢谢** > **多谢**
**感恩** is used exclusively in formal context while **多谢** is only used casually. **感谢** and **谢谢** can be used at the user's discretion, though the former sounds more formal.

Comment: Is such usage more common in Taiwan than in mainland China? For example, I had the impression that a Taiwanese would say something like "我帮忙他完成了一件事" whereas someone from the Mainland would say "我帮他完成了一件事". Here "帮忙" is a similar verb-noun phrase (to me) but used as a verb.

Comment: @HerrK.I edited my answer to address your first question regarding 感恩. I am not familiar with its usage in Taiwan. In mainland China, 帮忙 is either used by itself (as an intransitive verb: 他来帮忙) or with the task you're to help with (他来帮忙搬家 - "搬家" is the task here).

Comment: I think "感恩XX" sounds like the style of Chinese in Taiwan.

Comment: I heart it from HK and TW people who are religious. I interpret as a short and sweet way to say "I feel grateful".

Comment: @Mathaholic Do you think people in Taiwan will use 感恩 in less formal settings? If that is the case I will edit my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @judester I think it is common for people to use words that will otherwise be considered too formal when they are talking about religion.

Comment: @CosmosGu yes you're right, however, they will use the term in discussions not related to religion, and in place of just saying a standard thank you.

Comment: @judester I see. Maybe constantly using this word in religious context "desensitized" it for them? :)

Comment: @CosmosGu I don't think so...I think religious people are more likely to express their sense of gratefulness. For a lack of better word.

Comment: @judester I get you. I had a similar experience with some of my religious friends.

Answer (score 0):

Often we say "感谢" in the oral conversation, but "感恩" is also used in oral, the meaning is more deep. I will give a example:

生活中，我们要学会感恩。

Comment: But in your example "感恩" is not a verb; it's a verb-noun phrase.